# mysql query to display values with same same in first rows then in second row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a few many rows in mysql table.I want to get the values sorted like rows with value 1 in first row rows with value 2 in second row and so on . My table look like this,

```
id   Columnn1 Column2 name
1     1       1        a
2     2       2        b
3     2       3        c
4     3       2        d
5     3       2        e
```

I want the result as

```
a in first row
b,c in second row
d,e in third row
```

that is order by Columnn1

Comment: I was going to post an answer, but you killed your own question by showing no effort.

Comment: `SELECT Column1, GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM yourTable GROUP BY Column1`

Comment: use  GROUP_CONCAT(name)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select group_concat(name) as res from tbl_name order by column1 group by column1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below query

```
select id,column1,column2,group_concat(name) from table_name
group by column2 order by column2
```

Answer (score 0):

use `GROUP_CONCAT(name)` function returns a string with `concatenated and separated by comma` non-NULL value from a group.

```
select group_concat(name) from tbl_name order by column1 group by column1;
```